# How to create a webmap/app where a user can select features by location by drawing a polygon?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I would like to share a simple webapp service with colleagues whereby users can draw polygons on a map and features which intersect their drawn layer are selected and their attributes returned. I've had a look on the ArcGIS online help pages and found [this](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c3738c8d66c343459479c794b2086b69) which seems helpful but the URL for the app has expired.

Is anyone able to offer some pointers as to where to begin?

Answer (score 2):

I use a custom widget called Enhanced Search for that. More information can be found about it and it can be downloaded from [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/119278). Other custom widgets in WAB are listed on the webpage as well.